# Decrementing a number in c as an argument

Tags: c

**Note**: I am a beginner to the world of C language.
I was trying to write a program that calculates the sum of N natural number.
Here it is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum_of_N_with_recursion(int N);

int main()
{
    int n,result;
    do
    {
        printf("enter a natural number : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n<0)
        {
            printf("%d is not a natural number\n",n);
        }
    }while(n<0);
    result = sum_of_N_with_recursion(n);
    printf("sum of the first %d natural numbers is %d\n",n,result);    

    return 0;
}


int sum_of_N_with_recursion(int N)
{
    if(N==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return  N + sum_of_N_with_recursion(N--);
}
```

*What is my problem?*

When I tried to decrement N in the **sum_of_N_number()** like this `sum_of_N_number(N--)` but it doesn't work. Why?

*Example*: `sum_of_N_number(3)` should equal to **6** but I got **3**!!

Comment: Read about pre-increment/decrement and post-incrementc/decrement. Also, your do/while loop should start with `do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
return  N + sum_of_N_with_recursion(N--);
```

You're both reading the value of `N` and writing the value of `N` in the same expression without a sequence point in between.  Attempting to do so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You don't actually need to change the value of `N` here.  You just want to pass in the value `N-1`, so do that instead:

```
return  N + sum_of_N_with_recursion(N-1);
```

Comment: Re: “You're both reading the value of `N` and writing the value of `N` in the same expression without a sequence point in between”: That is actually unknown. The function call has a sequence point and may be sequenced before the read of `N` and must be sequenced after the modification of `N`. But the call may be sequenced after the read too; it is indeterminate (different from unsequenced). In one case the read and the modification are sequenced. In the other, they are unsequenced. The behavior is then undefined because of a rule that if any ordering yields the unsequenced interaction,…

Comment: … the behavior is undefined, regardless of which ordering the compiler picks. So the conclusion is the same, but the required reasoning is complicated. We have had other questions involving function calls in which the indeterminate sequencing results in no undefined behavior even with multiple modifications to an object in the expression.